# Dataweave Filter and groupBy

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I tried to implement API in mule

From below CSV data I am looking to implement

```
Region,Country,ItemType,SalesChannel,OrderPriority,OrderDate,OrderID,ShipDate,UnitsSold,UnitPrice,UnitCost,TotalRevenue,TotalCost,TotalProfit
Central America and the Caribbean,Antigua and Barbuda ,Baby Food,Online,M,12/20/2013,957081544,1/11/2014,552,255.28,159.42,140914.56,87999.84,52914.72
Central America and the Caribbean,Panama,Snacks,Offline,C,7/5/2010,301644504,7/26/2010,2167,152.58,97.44,330640.86,211152.48,119488.38
Europe,Czech Republic,Beverages,Offline,C,9/12/2011,478051030,9/29/2011,4778,47.45,31.79,226716.10,151892.62,74823.48
Asia,North Korea,Cereal,Offline,L,5/13/2010,892599952,6/15/2010,9016,205.70,117.11,1854591.20,1055863.76,798727.44
Asia,Sri Lanka,Snacks,Offline,C,7/20/2015,571902596,7/27/2015,7542,152.58,97.44,1150758.36,734892.48,415865.88
Middle East and North Africa,Morocco,Personal Care,Offline,L,11/8/2010,412882792,11/22/2010,48,81.73,56.67,3923.04,2720.16,1202.88
Australia and Oceania,Federated States of Micronesia,Clothes,Offline,H,3/28/2011,932776868,5/10/2011,8258,109.28,35.84,902434.24,295966.72,606467.52
Europe,Bosnia and Herzegovina,Clothes,Online,M,10/14/2013,919133651,11/4/2013,927,109.28,35.84,101302.56,33223.68,68078.88
Middle East and North Africa,Afghanistan,Clothes,Offline,M,8/27/2016,579814469,10/5/2016,8841,109.28,35.84,966144.48,316861.44,649283.04
Sub-Saharan Africa,Ethiopia,Baby Food,Online,M,4/13/2015,192993152,5/7/2015,9817,255.28,159.42,2506083.76,1565026.14,941057.62
Middle East and North Africa,Turkey,Office Supplies,Offline,C,9/25/2013,557156026,10/15/2013,3704,651.21,524.96,2412081.84,1944451.84,467630.00
Middle East and North Africa,Oman,Cosmetics,Online,M,5/12/2013,741101920,5/17/2013,7382,437.20,263.33,3227410.40,1943902.06,1283508.34
Asia,Malaysia,Cereal,Offline,L,7/31/2016,333942162,8/25/2016,9762,205.70,117.11,2008043.40,1143227.82,864815.58
Central America and the Caribbean,Saint Lucia,Cosmetics,Offline,H,7/6/2015,795100581,7/16/2015,6786,437.20,263.33,2966839.20,1786957.38,1179881.82
Central America and the Caribbean,Saint Vincent and the Grenadines,Baby Food,Online,L,11/28/2010,504313504,12/3/2010,6428,255.28,159.42,1640939.84,1024751.76,616188.08
Middle East and North Africa,Lebanon,Meat,Offline,H,12/17/2015,611629760,1/31/2016,3693,421.89,364.69,1558039.77,1346800.17,211239.60
Europe,Austria,Cereal,Offline,C,8/13/2014,987410676,9/6/2014,5616,205.70,117.11,1155211.20,657689.76,497521.44
Europe,Bulgaria,Office Supplies,Online,L,10/31/2010,672330081,11/29/2010,6266,651.21,524.96,4080481.86,3289399.36,791082.50
North America,Mexico,Beverages,Online,C,3/13/2017,127374303,3/20/2017,1742,47.45,31.79,82657.90,55378.18,27279.72
```

Sales Report. Endpoint should accept Sales Channel as parameter. It should return Total Number of Orders, Country, Order Priority, and Total Revenue. The data should be grouped by Country and Order Priority and only rows that match Sales Channel parameter

In task, I want to apply filter,map,groupBy
I tried below code but it’s not working

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

---
payload filter ($.SalesChannel == attributes.queryparam.salesChannel) map (item, index) -> {
        totalNumberofOrders: 100, 
        country: item.Country,
        orderPriority: item.OrderPriority,
        totalRevenue: item.TotalRevenue

} groupBy $.Country
```

Could you help me with what I did wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. groupBy() is being applied only to the object, not to the results of the mapping. Put parenthesis around the parameter of map().
2. The output of map() doesn't contains a Country key but a country key.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload filter ($.SalesChannel == attributes.queryparam.salesChannel) 
   map ((item, index) -> {
        totalNumberofOrders: 100, 
        country: item.Country,
        orderPriority: item.OrderPriority,
        totalRevenue: item.TotalRevenue
   })
   groupBy $.country
```